# Actualizar variable session con AJAX + PHP

Tags: php, ajax, session

estoy intentando actualizar una variable de sesión cada vez que se clica en un elemento del menú y por más que lo intento no lo consigo.

```
nav.blade.php

.
.
.
<a class="dropdown-item" onclick="actualizarSeccionActual({{ $seccion->id }})" href="">{{ $seccion->nombre }}</a>
.
.
.
<script type="text/javascript">
        function actualizarSeccionActual(valor){
            var url="seccionActual.php";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: valor,
                success:function(data){
                    console.log("tu varible de sesion tiene el valor de "+ data);
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

El código de la página PHP es el siguiente:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['seccion_actual'] = $_POST['valor'];
    return "hola";
?>
```

Cualquier ayuda será bienvenida. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar estas pasando mal los datos aquí `data: valor,` por ese motivo nunca vas a obtener el valor por `POST`, esto lo podrías hacer así:

`let datos = { "valor" : valor }`

y así puedes hacer esto en PHP `$_POST['valor'];`

**Posible ejemplo:**

*nav.blade.php*

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="dropdown-item" onclick="actualizarSeccionActual('valor_para_sesion')">Click me</a>
<br>
Valor sesion: <span id="valor"> <?php if (isset($_SESSION['seccion_actual'])) : echo $_SESSION['seccion_actual']; else : echo 'no existe sesion'; endif; ?> </span>

<script type="text/javascript">
function actualizarSeccionActual(valor){
    // Valor a pasar por POST
    let datos = { "valor" : valor },
        url="seccionActual.php";
    // Petición
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: datos,
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        // Un uso común de JSON es intercambiar datos desde un servidor web
        // JSON.parse; Convertimos los datos en un objeto JavaScript. 
        let respuesta = JSON.parse(data);

        // Respuesta es true
        if (respuesta.ok) {
            // Devuelves el nuevo valor de tu sesion a la consola
            console.log("tu varible de sesion tiene el valor de " + respuesta.valor);
            // Actualizas el valor de tu sesion si necesitas cambios en tu HTML
            document.getElementById('valor').innerHTML = respuesta.valor;
            // Actualizas la sesion PHP de la pagina mediante una recarga
            setTimeout(function(){ // hago un setTimeout para que veas los otros pasos en tu pantalla
                window.location.reload();
            },5000);
            
        } else {
            console.log(respuesta.error);
        }
            
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.error('hubo un error');
    })    
}
</script>
```

*seccionActual.php*
Aquí simplemente actualizas tu sesión con el valor obtenido por POST.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST)) :
    session_start();
    // Dato por POST
    $nuevo = $_POST['valor'] ?: '';
    // Creas tu nuevo sesion
    $_SESSION['seccion_actual'] = $_POST['valor'];
    //Quiero recordar par que este coga efecto, debes recargar la página o recargar algun div donde usas esta sesion.
    //
    // Respuesta Ajax
    //
    // Devolves el valor que quieres desde PHP
    echo json_encode(['ok'=> true, 'valor' => $nuevo, 'error'=> ""]);
else:
    // Error
    echo json_encode(['ok'=> false, 'valor' => '', 'error'=> "Hubo un problema con POST"]);
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

**No se puede.**

El código php se ejecuta en el servidor, y javascript se ejecuta en el cliente, esto quiere decir que para cuando se empieza a ejecutar el código AJAX, el de PHP no existe.

Comment: No es justamente para salvar esa restricción para lo que se usa AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que necesitas es guardar la sección actual, lo que podes hacer es utilizar las cookies, podes hacerlo directamente desde js. Te dejo dos links, uno con ejemplos y otro con una librería que me pareció muy util.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Comment: Muchas gracias @adrian-godoy pero preferiría no tener que usar cookies