# Como obtener el resultado de Query php en ajax?

Tags: php, html, mysql

agradezco a quien me pueda dar una luz sobre como poder avanzar.
En esta ocasión quisiera tener una guía sobre como tener el resultado de una consulta mySQL en AJAX
Necesito validar que el cometario que se va a editar en mi aplicación sea consultado por ID y correo, si el correo coincide con el id entonces deberá mostrar el modal para editar, pero si no coinciden entonces mostrar un modal de error informando que no tiene privilegios para editar ese comentario.
Mi código va de la siguiente manera:
Modal de verificación

```js
<script>
function verifyUser(userid){
    
    $('#validate').click(function() {
    var emailAdd = $('#u_email').val();
        //console.log(userid),
        //console.log(emailAdd),
    $.ajax({
        url:'verify.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data:{
            verifysend:userid,
            u_email: emailAdd,
            
        },
        
    success: function(data,status){

    // aquí debería recibir la respuesta del query y determinar que modal mostras según su respuesta.
    }
        
    });
    
    })
    }
    </script>
```

```html
Para llamar el modal uso esto

<html>
<body>

<!--Edit---><a  data-toggle="modal"data-target="#verify_modal"  onclick="verifyUser(<?php echo $rws['review_id'];?>)"><i class="fa fa-edit "></i></a>

</body>
</html>

<!---verify modal-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="verify_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header"> 
        <h5 class="modal-title">One more step before editing</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="false">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <label for="email">Before you can edit, we need to verify if was you who wrote the review, please enter your email and press verify</label>
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $rws['review_id']; ?>">
       
            <input type="text" name="u_email" id="u_email" class="form-control" placeholder="your-mail@domain.com" required /> 
    <span id="review_id"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit"  name="validate" id="validate" class="btn btn-primary">Verify</button>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Con esto ya me estoy asegurando que el id y el correo que escriba la persona se envian al archivo verify.php que contiene el siguiente código

```php
<?php

include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/conexion.php");

$lang="es";
if(isset($_POST['verifysend']) && isset($_POST['u_email'])){
    $unique=$_POST['verifysend'];
    $email=$_POST['u_email'];
    
    $sql="SELECT * from avatrade WHERE lang='$lang' review_id='$unique' AND user_email='$email'";
    
    $result= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    
    $numUsers = mysqli_num_rows($result);
 
    if($numUsers > 0) {
            echo "You can edit";// enviar respuesta si y abre modal edit
        }
        else
        {
    echo    "you can not edit this";}// enviar respuesta no y abrir modal error

}
?>
```

Ya después de pasar los datos al verify.php no tengo idea de como mostrar el modal de edición o de error según sea la respuesta del query.

ACTUALIZACIÓN #1: Me acabo de dar cuenta que los datos son pasados por ajax al verify.php, pero no retorna el resultado de la consulta.

Comment: Mira a ver si te puede ayudar esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/308120/actualizar-variable-session-con-ajax-php/501493#501493

Comment: No me sirvió, pero muchas gracias.

Comment: Fíjate que tienes ya problemas en tu AJAX. 1. los datos los estas pasando mal: ```verifysend:userid``` pon el nombre de la clave *verifysend* entre **comillas** "verifysend", lo mismo para **u_email**. 2. No entiendo muy bien la función del modal, con ```onclick="verifyUser(
)``` abres digamos el modal donde está el formulario donde tienes el otro botón que es el que va verificar mediante el AJAX? Si es así la parte del AJAX no podría ir en dentro de esa función. Luego la respuesta que te deje, la parte del AJAX te debería funcionar si lo has implementado bien, ¿cómo lo has intentado adaptar?

Comment: Hola, el modal es para que el usuario escriba el correo con el cual hizo la reseña en  el sitio, entonces capturamos el id + mas el correo y verificamos que en la base datos exista, si corresponde el ID + el email, significa que el usuario si escribió esa reseña ya que solo se permite una reseña por correo electrónico. el onclickverifyuser lo uso para tomar el ID del post al darle al boton editar.

Comment: Vale, aver si lo entiendo bien, quieres digamos verificar si el usuario ya puse una reseña, si es asi mostrar un modal para editar esa reseña y si no puso reseña un modal de error? Te vale un ejemplo en JavaScript, ya que estas apriendo.

Comment: Claro que si, aquí no hay logins ni regisatros, pero sabes se debe tener la posibilidad de editar lo que se ha escrito. el proceso lo estoy manejando a través de un modal, con el verifyuser, tomo la ID de la reseña, abro el modal, en el modal le solicito a la persona que escriba el correo usado para reseñar, con estos dos datos y a travez de la función verifyuser(userid) mando por ajax los datos el email y la ID, en verify.php hago la consulta en la base de datos y debo regresar una respuesta al ajax para que procese, si coinciden entonces abre el modal editmodal, si no el modal error

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135128/discussion-between-dbe-and-robin-ramirez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como falta bastante datos y tienes bastantes errores, te he creado un ejemplo que uso personalmente en JavaScript.

Podrías crear los modals que deseas simplemente creas un botón que se pasa el *data-id* que debe ser igual al *id* del modal y debe tener *class="modal__btn"*:

```
<a data-id="modal-1" class="modal__btn">abrir modal 1</a>
```

y luego el contenido del modal a llamar quedaría así:

```
<div id="modal-1" class="wrapper__modal">
   contenido
</div>
```

Si quieres más:

```
<a data-id="modal-2" class="modal__btn">abrir modal 2</a>
```

y

```
<div id="modal-2" class="wrapper__modal">
   contenido
</div>
```

Ahora vemos un ejemplo completo, use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript) para el envió del formulario

**Posible ejemplo:**

```js
/**
 * MODALS LAYOUT
 * 
 */

let modelButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.modal__btn')
let modal

// Obtenmos el Modal clickeado
modelButtons.forEach(function(item) {
  // Evento clic
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // data-id modal
    let x = e.target.dataset.id
    // Obtenemos el modal por el data-id
    modal = document.getElementById(x);
    // Display modal
    modal.style.display = "block"
    // Function fadeIn JS
    fadeIn(modal, 1000)
    // Close modal on click outside the modal
    outside(modal)
  })
})


// Cerrar modal si hacemos clic fuera del modal
function outside(modal) {
  window.onclick = function(e) {
    if (e.target == modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none"
    }
  }
}


/**
 * Function FadeIn parecido a jQuery :)
 * @param string (id element)
 * @param int (time)
 * @return FadeIn effect
 */
function fadeIn(el, time) {
  el.style.opacity = 0
  let last = +new Date()
  let tick = function() {
    el.style.opacity = +el.style.opacity + (new Date() - last) / time
    last = +new Date()

    if (+el.style.opacity < 1) {
      (window.requestAnimationFrame && requestAnimationFrame(tick)) || setTimeout(tick, 16)
    }
  }
  tick()
}


// FORMULARIO VERIFICAR

// Obtenemos el formulario para verificar si ya tiene reseña o no
let frmVerificar = document.getElementById("frm-verificar");

// Formulario existe
if (frmVerificar != null) {
  // Evento submit
  frmVerificar.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {

    // Creamos nueva solicitud
    //
    // Este es un objecto
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Respuesta
    request.onload = function(ev) {
      //alert(this.responseText)

      let responseJson = null
      try {
        // Obtenemos respuesta en UN JSON
        responseJson = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
        // ERROR  
      } catch (ev) {
        console.error('No se puede devolver un JSON!')
      }
      // Enviamos datos a funcion        
      if (responseJson) {
        RespuestaVerificar(responseJson)
      }
    };

    // Obtenemos datos desde el formulario
    setdataform = new FormData(frmVerificar)

    request.open("POST", "verificar.php");
    request.send(setdataform);
    ev.preventDefault();
  }, false);
}

/**
 * Control / Display the response data
 * @param {*} responseJson 
 */

function RespuestaVerificar(responseJson) {

  // Caja <ul> que va mostrar el mensaje de error
  let output = document.getElementById("mensaje__respuesta__verificar");

  // Remove current errors
  while (output.firstChild) {
    output.removeChild(output.firstChild)
  }
  // Create msg 
  responseJson.messages.forEach((message) => {
    const li = document.createElement('li')
    li.textContent = message
    output.appendChild(li)
  })

  // Respuesta es verdadero, abrimos modal editar
  if (responseJson.ok) {

    // Cerramos modal actual
    modal_verificar = document.getElementById('modal-verificar');
    // Display modal none
    modal_verificar.style.display = "none"

    // Abrimos modal editar
    modal = document.getElementById('modal-editar');
    // Display modal
    modal.style.display = "block"
    // Function fadeIn JS
    fadeIn(modal, 1000)
    // Close modal on click outside the modal
    outside(modal)

    // Mensaje de error, o abres un modal error  
  } else {

    // Mostramos el mensaje
    output.style.display = 'block';
    // Tras x segundos quitamos el mensaje
    setTimeout(function() {
      output.style.display = 'none';
    }, 12000);

  }
}
// Fin formulario verificar

// Creas tu request como el codigo de arriba para tu formulario editar, esta parte de lo dejo para ti, para que no todo sea copiar y pegar
// Y asi aprendes :)
```

```css
/**
    * Modal default layout
    *
    */

.modal__btn {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrapper__modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

.modal__inner {
  cursor: auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #e6f2ff;
  margin: 6.25rem auto 3.125rem auto;
  border: 0.0625rem solid #888;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 25rem;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* The Close Button (x) */

.btn__close__modal {
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  margin-right: 0.625rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color.2s ease-in-out;
}

.btn__close__modal:hover,
.btn__close__modal:focus {
  color: blue;
  transition: color;
}

.frm__response,
.frm__response.success {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  display: none;
  border: 0.0625rem solid red;
  background-color: red;
  border-left: 0.1875rem solid var(--body-color);
  color: var(--body-color);
  padding: 0.625rem;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  max-width: 14.0625rem;
}

.frm__response li,
.frm__response.success li {
  list-style-type: square;
  margin-left: 0.9375rem;
}

.frm__response.success {
  border: 0.0625rem solid #008b58;
  background-color: #04AA6D;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/871fadbdf5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!--Edit--->
<i class="modal__btn fa fa-edit" data-id="modal-verificar">Edit</i>

<!---verify modal-->
<div id="modal-verificar" class="wrapper__modal">
  <div class="modal__inner">

    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title">One more step before editing</h5>
      <button class="btn__close__modal" onclick="document.getElementById('modal-verificar').style.display='none'" title="Cerrar"><i class="far fa-window-close"></i></button>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
      <form id="frm-verificar" method="POST">

        <label for="email">
          Before you can edit, we need to verify if was you who wrote the review, please enter your email and press verify
        </label>

        <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="es">
        <!-- no lo vi en tu codigo en cambio aparece $lang en tu sentencia -->
        <input type="hidden" name="review_id" value="1">
        <!-- $rws['review_id'] -->
        <input type="text" name="u_email" placeholder="your-mail@domain.com" />

        <button type="submit">Verify</button>
        <ul id="mensaje__respuesta__verificar" class="frm__response"></ul>

      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn__close__modal" onclick="document.getElementById('modal-verificar').style.display='none'" title="Cerrar"><i class="far fa-window-close"></i></button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>


<!-- modal editar-->
<div id="modal-editar" class="wrapper__modal">
  <div class="modal__inner">

    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title">Editar</h5>
      <button class="btn__close__modal" onclick="document.getElementById('modal-editar').style.display='none'" title="Cerrar"><i class="far fa-window-close"></i></button>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
      creas tu formulario editar
      <form id='frm_editar' method="POST">

        <input type="text" name="resena" placeholder="reseña" />

        <button type="submit">Editar</button>
        <ul id="mensaje__respuesta__editar" class="frm__response"></ul>

      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn__close__modal" onclick="document.getElementById('modal-editar').style.display='none'" title="Cerrar"><i class="far fa-window-close"></i></button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Veamos el codigo de PHP para verificar si tiene reseña o no, y segun el caso mostrarmos el modal editar o error.

**verificar.php**

```
<?php

$ok = true;
$messages = [];

if (isset($_POST)) :

    // Obtener datos formulario
    $unique = $_POST['review_id'] ?? '';
    $email = $_POST['u_email'] ?? '';
    $lang = $_POST['lang'] ?? '';

    // Comprobamos datos validos
    if (empty($email)) :
        $ok = false;
        $messages[] = 'El correo electronico esta vacio';
    endif;

    // Email invalido
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) :
        $ok = false;
        $messages[] = 'El correo electronico no es valido';
    endif;

    // Datos son verdaderos
    if ($ok && $unique && $email && $lang) :

        // SQL
        $sql = "SELECT count(*) as existe from avatrade WHERE lang = ? AND review_id= ? AND user_email = ?";
        // Sentencia preparada
        if ($sentencia = $conn->prepare($sql)) :

            $sentencia->bind_param('sis', $lang, $unique, $email);
            $sentencia->execute();
            $sentencia->bind_result($existe);
            $sentencia->fetch();

            // Existe reseña
            if ($existe > 0) :
                $messages[] = 'Abrimos modal editar';
            else:
                $ok = false;
                $messages[] = 'No tienes ningun review';
            endif;
        else :
            $ok = false;
            $messages[] = 'Problemas sentencia';
        endif;    
    endif;

    // Devolvemos respuesta 
    echo json_encode(
        array(
            'ok' => $ok,
            'messages' => $messages
        )
    );
endif;
```

Manual [sentencia preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: Gracias, con este código me diste una luz para avanzar.

Comment: De nada amigo, pruébalo aparte y así veras que funciona bien, y poco a poco lo implementas a tu proyecto. Si tienes alguna duda, me preguntas.